# count events based on transitions between two variables R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create an event counter that counts the number of events based on transitions in two variables, `var1` and `var2`. In the hypothetical data frame the expected behaviour is in the `event` column.

```
dt <- data.frame(var1 = c(-1, 1),
                   var2 = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B'),
                   event = c(1, 1, 2, 2))
```

In the above dataframe using `match`, `unique` and `group_by` does not give the desired behaviour.

```
dt %>% 
    group_by(var2) %>% 
    mutate(event2 = match(var1, unique(var1)))
```

However when I create a data frame with 3 instances of var1 and var2

```
dt2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(rep(-1, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(-1, 3)),
                   var2 = c(rep('A', 3), rep('B', 3), rep('A', 3), rep('B', 3)),
                   event = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6)))
```

Using `match`, `unique` and `group_by` reproduces the desired behaviour. What its the reason for this and is there a way to create an event counter (or id) that identifies unique instances of 1 and -1 in var1 along with unique instances of A and B in var2 and increments an event counter irrespective of the number of values of 1, -1 and A, B in var1 and var2 respectively.

Comment: Do you need `mutate(event2 =  row_number())`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "transitions in two variables?"

Comment: please see edits. The suggestion from @akrun works for dt but not for dt2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` and `lag`. `cumsum(var2 == "A")` implies that every time `var2 == "A"`, the counter gets incremented by one. To make this happen only for the first A, you can add another condition, which is that `lag(var2) != "A"`, meaning that `var2` must be equal to `"A"` and that its previous value must not be `"A"`. The default parameter is the value for the first element (default is NA, but here it is set to `"B"`).

```r
library(dplyr)
dt2 %>% 
  mutate(event = cumsum(var2 == "A" & lag(var2, default = "B") != "A"))

   var1 var2 event
1    -1    A     1
2    -1    A     1
3    -1    A     1
4     1    B     1
5     1    B     1
6     1    B     1
7     1    A     2
8     1    A     2
9     1    A     2
10   -1    B     2
11   -1    B     2
12   -1    B     2
```

Comment: please edited question. Whilst this solution works for dt, it doesn't reproduce the desired behaviour for dt2.

Comment: Then you can add a condition where only first A are used to compute the cumsum.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mael. That works a treat and I can confirm it works irrespective of the number of values of 1, -1 and A, B in var1 and var2. If you dont mind, it would be great if you were able to articulate what your functions are doing under the hood to aim understanding. Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: Hope it's clearer now!